# Parse.com get the username if its facebook or a parse user

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

To get the current username i use: NSString *userName = [[PFUser currentUser] username]; The problem is that if the user is logged with FB i get some string like 'u55yceub4z2yzrezbdfpyx3bl' and not the real username.

I know i can get it with:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
    NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
    NSString *userName = userData[@"name"];
}}];
```

But the question is, is there any way to get the username forgetting is the user is logged with Parse or Facebook? If it is negative, how can i know the user i logged via facebook to get the proper username ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PFFacebookUtils` `- isLinkedWithUser:`